# Microphone not working

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, skype, alsa, microphone

My sound input device stopped working without any update or changes in the system. I've tried several ways to make it work, including reinstalling PulseAudio, checking alsamixer, mute buttons, etc.. Running Pulse Audio Control, doesn't show any input sound progress, and in the box named "Port", there's two options: "Microphone" and "Analog input".
In alsamixer, everything is normal and the mic's volume is max. 
I didn't change any of the settings when the mic stopped working. I don't know what happened. In skype, I disabled the automatic settings and still didn't work.

Can anyone help me? Please!

Comment: have you tried the mic in different programs?

Comment: [This page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1386638) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a laptop or a desktop?
My laptop mic used to work awfully after every travel: I blame bad cabling.

I will try an external mic (or a different one) to verify if the problem is hardware or sw.

Can you confirm it doesn't work with any mic?